# Xamarin: Label disappears inside ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Project is being made for an Android device.

I have searched for a while now and can't find an answer to why this happens.

```
<ListView x:Name="ScorebdList"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
          Grid.RowSpan="4"
          SelectionMode="None"
          Header="HIGHSCORES">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Score}" HeightRequest="50" 
                                   MinimumHeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" 
                                   MinimumWidthRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                   BackgroundColor="Red"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Explanation:
Here I am trying to set the **height and width** of the Label and same for Grid.
Red background on label to see where it goes.

This is not showing Label **at all**.

**If I were to do this:**

```
<ListView x:Name="ScorebdList"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
          Grid.RowSpan="4"
          SelectionMode="None"
          Header="HIGHSCORES"
          HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Score}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                   BackgroundColor="Red"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

*I added HasUnevenRows attribute and set size and width in grid to auto. Also removed height/width requests of Label.*

Now the Label will show, but not as I want it to.

**Other things I tested:**
I have also tried setting the Label inside a `<StackLayout>` instead of Grid with the same results.
(Inside the `<ViewCell>`)
Also tried using a `<TextCell>` instead of `<ViewCell>`, which I could not center but fix the height and width...

**Question is:**
Why? What am I missing?

Using the second code example is not how I want it to look.
**I want my `<ListView>` to show highscores in the center of the view with the height and width I set.**

(Code below for the images have different colors than above code, Label is #D87040(orange ish) and grid background is #321F1F(Dark red)")
**Here are two images, first image is with width/height to '*'.**

[image: Width and Height is *]

**Here are second image where i set definition to 50 on w/h.**
[image: Width and height are set to 50]

Comment: try setting the height value of the Grid, not the Label.  And/or set the RowHeight of the ListView

Comment: Tried both. The thing is that when I do that the rows get the right height as wanted but
the Label dissappears completely... and no score is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem were really strange, but thanks alot to you all who helped me!

In the end I used `Margin="-50"` to set the Grid.
Still strange that i could not use height requests, row/column spacing... and even more.

But it is solved for now, thanks again!

With `Margin="-50 0"`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` has no `ItemSource` binding

Answer (score 0):

Use a Converter to change the Grid Row Height with the Listview RowHeight.

Converter:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }     

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
   
}
```

Xaml:

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView
        x:Name="ScorebdList"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.RowSpan="4"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Header="HIGHSCORES"
        RowHeight="100"
        SelectionMode="None"
        HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Source={x:Reference ScorebdList}, Path=RowHeight, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label
                                BackgroundColor="Red"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{Binding score}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
 public partial class Page17 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Score> scores { get; set; }
    public Page17()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        scores = new ObservableCollection<Score>()
        {
            new Score{ score="Score1"},
            new Score{ score="Score2"},
            new Score{ score="Score3"},

        };
        ScorebdList.ItemsSource = scores;
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
public class Score
{
    public string score { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that code works for it's purpose but do not fix my problem. 
I can adjust the column height and width, but when i do the label dissappears.

Comment: For the code i provided, change the column height and width, but the label still exists. Could you provide more details about the disappearance?

Comment: As soon as I set the height or widht to the definitions, Label dissappears. 
So your code do work, but not showing the Label for me. If I use your code witouht setting the height and widht, the Label shows. It feels like I'm missing something simple here...

Answer (score 0):

From your code i see that you never set `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` to your label

```
<Label Text="{Binding Score}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
    BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not needed. But tried it with the same results.

Comment: From the code of your first image, I guess you need to set `ColumnSpacing="0"` and `RowSpacing="0"` to your grid

Comment: Yeah that was a good idea! You really helped me solve it!
For some reason setting spacing do nothing, strange. BUT instead i used 
**Margin="-50"** and that actually worked.

Comment: Glad to heard that